# Add values to a std::multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

I'm trying to print out the five most used values. But when I changed my map to a multimap I broke the code where I add values to the map. How can I add values to a multimap? Can it be done in a similar way as I add values to a map?

```
// Create a map for keeping track of how many occurences of the different colors
    multimap<string, int> hexmap;

    // Add the hex values to the map
        for(int i = 0; i < imagesize; i ++)
        {
            hexmap[colors[i]]++;
        }

        typedef std::multimap<int, string> Mymap;
        Mymap dst;

        std::transform(hexmap.begin(), hexmap.end(), 
                   std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                   [](const std::pair<string,int> &p ) 
                   { 
                     return std::pair<int, string>(p.second, p.first); 
                   }
                   );


        Mymap::iterator st = dst.begin(),it;
        size_t count = 5;
        for(it = st; ( it != dst.end() ) &&  ( --count ); ++it)
        std::cout << it->second << it->first << endl;
```

Comment: You might be interested in Boost.Bimap.

Comment: multimaps don't support access via `operator[]`, so your `hexmap[colors[i]]++` line isn't valid. Is there a reason you turned `hexmap` into a multimap? it seems like it could have stayed as regular map.

Comment: @alecbenzer yes I wanted to recive the five top values from hexmap and there are more than one that has the same mapped value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I'm trying to print out the five most used values."*

In this case, you don't have to use `hexmap` as `std::multimap` just `std::map` will do the job

However `std::multimap` for `dst` should be required

Comment: @POW I changed it and I don't get an error now but it begins from the smallest value to the highest. How would one change how it writes out the data?

Answer (score 2):

You add elements to a `std::multimap<K, V>` using `insert()` or `emplace()`, e.g.:

```
std::multimap<std::string, int> map;
map.insert(std::make_pair("hello" , 1));
map.insert({ "world", 0 });
map.emplace("hello", 0);
```

You'd locate objects in the `std::multimap<K, V>` using it's `find()` member, e.g.:

```
std::multimap<std::string, int>::iterator it = map.find("hello");
```